# Nested grid does not stay expanded after PageIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, gridview, nested

I am trying to figure out how to keep my nested grid expanded after I move to the next page.
This is my markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMger" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:GridView ID="UserGroupGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="javascript:DivExpandCollapse('div<%# Eval("GroupID")%>');">
    <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("GroupID")%>" alt="" width="25px" border="0" src="Images/plus.png" /> </a> 
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GroupID">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="uggvLblGroupID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField> 
  <div id="div<%# Eval("GroupID") %>" style="display:none">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlNestedGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:GridView ID="GroupMemberGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GroupMemberGridView_RowDeleting" 
  OnRowCommand="GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"                         onpageindexchanging="GroupMemberGridView_PageIndexChanging" onpageindexchanged="GroupMemberGridView_PageIndexChanged">
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberID">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>               
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" 
    class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my javascript that is at the top of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(
            function ExpandGrid(groupID) {
                var div = document.getElementById(groupID);
                var img = document.getElementById('img' + groupID);
                div.style.display = "inline";
                img.src = "Images/minus.png";
                $(div + ".chosen-single").chosen("destroy");
                $(div + ".chosen-single").chosen({
                    search_contains: true,
                    width: "100%",
                    no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
                });
             });
        }
</script>
```

This is the PageIndexChanged method that calls the javascript:

```
protected void GroupMemberGridView_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)sender;              
 int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32((tgvGroupMember.Parent.FindControl("uggvLblGroupID") as Label).Text);
 UpdatePanel updatePnl = (UpdatePanel)tgvGroupMember.Parent.FindControl("updatePnlNestedGrid");
 string strJavascriptFnCall = "ExpandGrid(" + tiGroupID.ToString() + ")";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePnl, updatePnl.GetType(), "ExpandGrid", strJavascriptFnCall, true);
}
```

In debug, when the ExpandGrid() javascript function is called, I get the error:  ExpandGrid() is not defined.

The function is between  tags and at the top of the page.
Why is it not defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my nested grid to remain expanded after paging.
This is how I fixed it...
First, I removed `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest` from the javascript so that the function looked like this:

```
function ExpandGrid(groupID) {
        var div = document.getElementById(groupID);
        alert("groupID: " + groupID + " div: " + div);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + groupID);
        div.style.display = "inline";
        img.src = "Images/minus.png";
        $(div + ".chosen-single").chosen("destroy");
        $(div + ".chosen-single").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            width: "100%",
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
        });
```

Then within the PageIndexChanged I correctly named the parameter and surrounded it in single quotes:

```
string strJavascriptFnCall = "ExpandGrid('div" + tiGroupID.ToString() + "')";
```

Finally, I put the UpdatePanel **outside** the div, not inside it as shown above.

That got it to work.
I hope this can help someone.